# WSE Settings 2.0 in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wse

I am updating an application which communicates with a third party system using WSE and DIME attachments. The current solution is writen in VS2003 and .Net framework 1.1 and I am looking to update it so that it is developed in VS2008 using.Net 2.0 initially and then later .Net 3.5. I have no scope to update the third party application so migrating to WCF is not an option.

I can load my solution without a problem in VS2008 but I no longer have the option to set the WSE 2.0 settings by right clicking on the project file In VS2003 I get an additional menu item for WSE Settings 2.0 if I click on a project but this option is not present in VS2008. The net result is that when I create a web reference with the third party system from VS2008, it does not create the WSE elements of the interface and my application will not compile.

The VS203 and VS2008 environments are on the same system (VS2008 was installed after WSE) so I am at a loss to understand why this option has disappeared. Any help/guidance on adding WSE to the list of add-ins for VS2008 would be much appreciated.

Comment: +1 Did you get any further with this? I have to do a very similar thing now.

Comment: +1. Same here. @Robin Day, @Nigel Tunnicliffe, Did either of you find a solution?  Even if the answer is "you can't do it this way, use WCF - here is an article explaining how" would be worth an upvote from me, and likely anyone else who is going to have to face this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not supported. I think it's a passive aggressive plan by Microsoft to encourage people to use WCF instead.

Having said that, this may be of some use...
http://dotnetstep.blogspot.com/2009/04/wse-30-setting-tool-for-visual-studio.html